# do i need to add each controller class namespace in routes

Tags: php, laravel, routes, controller

I'm learning laravel and it is laravel 8.40. Everytime, I create route and controller for it, i have to add it in routes like this.

```php
use App\Http\Controllers\Form;
use App\Http\Controllers\Form2;
use App\Http\Controllers\TestForm;
use App\Http\Controllers\User;
use App\Http\Controllers\User_2;
use App\Http\Controllers\TableForm;
use App\Http\Controllers\UserProfileHandle;
use App\Http\Controllers\Sessions;
```

how can i stop doing this? I have read about autoloading the classes, but where should I have to make changes to make this happen

Comment: You have to add it in the routes so you can refer to it just by it's class name rather than the full name e.g. if you have `use App\Http\Controllers\Form;` then you can use `Form::class` to refer to `App\Http\Controllers\Form`. This has nothing to do with autoloading. You do this in the case you have multiple classes with the same name in your project (or dependencies) so you can be explicit to which ones you are referring to

Comment: thanks @apokryfos, you mean in App\providers\routeServiceProviders.php, the second property with 
```php  // protected $namespace = 'App\\Http\\Controllers'; ```,
 i uncomment this line, and everything will be set good, right???

or i'll add all the classes in seperate file and then that paricular one php file, i include() in routes?? is this is the same

Comment: If you uncomment that line then you don't have to have `use ...` for your controllers but you have to put all your controllers under `App\Http\Controllers` or have a separate namespace declaration in your route definitions for controllers  you want to put elsewhere

Comment: thanks @apokryfos, thats great
suppose if i have many controllers like app\http\controllers\admin\myController.php, does the solution still be the same?

Comment: If you use `protected $namespace = 'App\Http\Controllers';` you'd have to refer to the controller as e.g. `Route::get('admin/myAction', 'admin\myController@action')`

Comment: actually it is laravel 8, and the controller className@function is not supported, now it is ```php Route::get('admin/myAction', [admin\myController::class, 'action'] ``` , actually there are bunch of classes and everytime I have to import it by ```use``` or like this ```Admin\Controllers\FormController::class``` etc , i want to get rid of the rest path of namespace, I want to use only ```php Route::get('show', [Show::class, 'doSomething']) ```

Comment: Laravel 8 does still support the `'controllername@function'` syntax. It is just discouraged

Answer (score 3):

You need to add a namespace property in the `app\Providers\RouteServiceProvider.php`

```
protected $namespace = 'App\Http\Controllers';
```